# Apple Pay Web: startSession error "The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm"

Tags: applepay-web

Trying to implement Apple Pay into a asp.net web site (Framework 8).
When we make a call to "https://apple-pay-gateway-cert.apple.com/paymentservices/startSession" I am getting the following error.

```
"The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm."
```

[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
public static string GenerateSession(string validationURL)
{
validationURL = "https://apple-pay-gateway-cert.apple.com/paymentservices/startSession";
string keyStoreFile = "C:\ApplePay\merchant_id.cer";
X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(keyStoreFile);
X509Certificate2Collection clientCertificates = new X509Certificate2Collection(clientCertificate);
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(validationURL);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Accept = "application/json";
request.ClientCertificates = clientCertificates;
using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
dynamic credentials = new JObject();
credentials.merchantIdentifier = "merchant.abc.abcd.sandbox";
credentials.domainName = "abc-xyz.abcd.edu";
credentials.displayName = "Company";
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(credentials);
streamWriter.Write(json);
streamWriter.Flush();
streamWriter.Close();
}
StringBuilder responseStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
try
{
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
using (StreamReader responseStreamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
{
string line;
while ((line = responseStreamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
responseStringBuilder.Append(line);
}
}
return responseStringBuilder.ToString();
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
using (WebResponse errorResponse = ex.Response)
using (StreamReader errorStreamReader = new StreamReader(errorResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
string errorMessage = errorStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
return errorMessage;
}
}
}

Any help would be greatly appreciated.